# How do I get VIM to remember the line I was on when I reopen a file?

Tags: vim

I just moved from RH/Fedora to Ubuntu 12.04.  In RedHat, when I reopen a file with VIM, it opens with the cursor on the line it was on when I closed the file.  However, what I am seeing now is that when I reopen a file, the cursor is always at the top, **every** time.  As some of the files I am working with are 20k lines long, this gets a bit old quickly.

I installed the full version of VIM via apt-get on my new Ubuntu so that I could use the arrow keys in insert mode.  The version that is printed out is VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3.

Any help at all would be gratefully welcomed.

Comment: If you want to open more file with the lines these files was opened earlier use :mksession . For further details see the help of :mksession and [Managing Sessions](http://vim.runpaint.org/editing/managing-sessions/)

Comment: For those who voted this down as already been answered, I believe mine was asked first.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Add the following lines to your `~/.vimrc` or global `/etc/vim/vimrc`

```
if has("autocmd")
  au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 0 && line("'\"") <= line("$") | exe "normal! g`\"" | endif
endif
```

This will jump to the last known cursor position unless:

- the position is invalid
- the position is inside an event handler

Comment: It works by creating an autocommand for the BufReadPost event -- i.e. a vim command that is executed every time after vim loads a file from disk.  The command checks if the `"` mark is defined and sensible (the `"` mark stores the last position in the current file and is saved in the `~/.viminfo` file), and if so, tells vim to jump to it.

Comment: Thank! At times (such as `:help`) I'm getting `E32: No file name`, any advice?

Comment: I've done this for both ~/.vimrc and /etc/vim/vimrc and even restarted, still always opens at the first line!

Comment: @Nagev check the permission of ~/.viminfo. I changed the owner and group to mine, and it works.

Comment: I did this, but vi always open in a fixed line, this doesn't update the viminfo file

Comment: one-liner:   echo -e 'if has("autocmd")\n  au BufReadPost * if line("'\''\"") > 0 && line("'\''\"") <= line("$") | exe "normal! g`\"" | endif\nendif' >> ~/.vimrc

Answer (score 11):

Your system probably already contains the necessary feature. You just need to uncomment it in the default configuration `/etc/vim/vimrc` or add it to your ~/.vimrc file. [vim is not remembering last position](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223018/vim-is-not-remembering-last-position)

```
" Uncomment the following to have Vim jump to the last position when
" reopening a file
if has("autocmd")
  au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") | exe "normal! g'\"" | endif
endif
```

This is an auto command that looks for line numbers of the evaluated expressions. The g command jumps to the last position if it was recorded. Using :help on commands BufReadPost, line() and g` will explain the details of how this works.