# vi settings look off in 16.04

Tags: vi

After starting to use Ubuntu 16.04, I find that many reasonable `vi` settings are off (before that I was on Scientific Linux, don't remember which version). This includes things like language highlighting, remembering the cursor's last line, search highlighting, remembering the last search, line number at screen bottom...

I tried to remedy some of these in `~/.vimrc` and in `/etc/vim/vimrc`, which didn't always work.

Before I go on tackling each of the problems individually, I wonder if there is something big that I'm missing which might account for lacking all of these?

**Edit:** 
It was suggested that this is a duplicate of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/434628/which-application-does-the-vi-command-open). Not exactly. It turns out that the answers in that question give a partial answer to this question if they are combined with the answers to a third question. Therefore, I add all this as an answer, since it would be useful to anyone else facing the same problem.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57155/discussion-on-question-by-helen-vi-settings-look-off-in-16-04).

Comment: @EricCarvalho: tl;dr The OP cannot know in advance that the linked question (partially) answers this one. Long reply: This has been debated a lot in the removed comments. I very strongly suggest to *not* mark this as a duplicate. The reason is that *a part* of the answer to this question can be found in the linked one, but there are *more parts* in the answer to this question, and if someone asks *this* question then they can't know that the answer hides in the other one which presupposes a different background by the person who asks the question.

Answer (score 2):

Check that you have the full `vim` package installed, and not just `vim-tiny`.

`vim-tiny` is a compact version of vim without many plugins.

Once you install the proper `vim` package you'll get the usual set of included vim plugins.  You may still have to add `:set nocompatible` to your .vimrc to use its full functionality.

Comment: Thanks, this actually should also involve changing the default to `vim` (actually I was going to edit my own answer to include this). However, there are still many features missing, to my dismay.

Comment: It may be that the vim defaults are just very plain, with much of the good stuff disabled unless you turn it on. Try the vim-sensible project which provides a good set of default settings - some distros and vim clones will use defaults like those (indeed neovim uses the ones from vim-sensible).

Comment: https://github.com/tpope/vim-sensible

Comment: I'll check this out!

Answer (score 0):

Two answers were pointed out in the comments which, when combined, seem to form a kind of answer:

`vi` now actually invokes `vim-tiny` (explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/434628/which-application-does-the-vi-command-open)), which has only a few features enabled by default (explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104138/what-features-does-vim-tiny-have)).

One can change this default by doing

```
sudo update-alternatives --config vi
```

I still don't know if everything could be amended in one single move, though. (Using `vim` "out of the box" still lacks many of those "standard" features.)

Comment: Syntax highlighting, search highlighting, etc. have to be enabled, and [remembering the last position as well](http://askubuntu.com/a/224908/158442). It might be your previous distro or system administrator kept default vimrc that enabled lots of stuff (I know I did), but the default configuration is minimal.

Comment: @muru: I see. It's a little weird however that my `/etc/vim/vimrc` came with very few options, so it's not just uncommenting them, I actively have to include them. (E.g. no search highlighting.)

Comment: @Helen adding detail to this answer explaining how you are actively including these options mentioned in your question, IMHO would have a positive impact on this answer.

Comment: Agreed, I'll deal with it soon.