# In some files, vim jumps to the last location on my last edit. In other files this does not happen

Tags: update-manager, vim, vimrc

I have just updated Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS with `Software Updater`.

After restarting, apparently something has changed on `vim`:

Previously, when opening a file with `vim`, then `:q`, and then opening it again, it automatically jumped to the last line I was reading.

After this update, when I open some files already saved in the computer, then `:q` and opening them again, they do jump to the line I was reading a minute ago, but other files do not, and are opened in line 1.

I have not modified anything

My `/etc/vim/vimrc` has uncommented these lines:

```
if has("autocmd")
  au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") | exe "normal! g'\"" | endif
endif
```

And my `~/.vimrc` has only one line:

```
syntax on
```

(All the files are normal text files)

EDIT:

The problematic files are in a folder path ~/work/(+1000 characters of folders and subfolders)/file.tex

Files on ~/work/folder1  do not present that problem.

Does the length of the path has something to do?

## Answering @EliahKagan questions / suggestions:

Let the `~/work/folder1/test_1.tex` be the file where the "jump to the last location" works well.

Let the `~/work/folder2/very-long-path-of-folders-and-subfolders--around_1000 characters_of_folders_and_subfolders/test_2.tex` be the file(s) where the "jump to the last location" is not working.

**1)** Can you add the output of `ls -l ~/.viminfo` to your question?

```
david@so1:~$ ls -l ~/.viminfo
-rw------- 1 david david 330206 Jul  9 22:08 /home/david/.viminfo
```

**2)** Are the files for which you are not having the problem files that you typically edit by running `vim` as root?

No, I run them as user:

```
david@so1:~$ vi  ~/work/folder1/test_1.tex
```

**3)** What is the output of `file /etc/alternatives/vim`

```
david@so1:~/work/folder1$ file /etc/alternatives/vim
/etc/alternatives/vim: symbolic link to `/usr/bin/vim.gtk3'
```

**4)** Do you know what packages the Software Updater installed, upgraded, or removed? `/var/log/apt/history.log`

```
david@so1:~/work/folder1$ /var/log/apt/history.log
bash: /var/log/apt/history.log: Permission denied
```

And as `root`:

```
david@so1:~/work/folder1$ sudo su
root@so1:/home/david/work/folder1# /var/log/apt/history.log
bash: /var/log/apt/history.log: Permission denied
```

If I open the `/var/log/apt/history.log` file:

```
david@so1:~/work/folder1$ vim /var/log/apt/history.log
```

I see the following:

```
Start-Date: 2017-07-03  22:05:01
Commandline: apt-get install pandoc
Install: pandoc:amd64 (1.12.2.1-1build2), pandoc-data:amd64 (1.12.2.1-1build2, automatic)
End-Date: 2017-07-03  22:05:04

Start-Date: 2017-07-09  18:54:46
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.682'
Install: linux-headers-4.4.0-83-generic:amd64 (4.4.0-83.106~14.04.1), linux-image-4.4.0-83-generic:amd64 (4.4.0-83.106~14.04.1), linux-headers-4.4.0-83:amd64 (4.4.0-83.106~14.04.1), linux-signed-image-4.4.0-83-generic:amd64 (4.4.0-83.106~14.04.1), linux-image-extra-4.4.0-83-generic:amd64 (4.4.0-83.106~14.04.1)
```

**5)** I have noticed a very interesting thing:

```
david@so1:~$ sudo su
[sudo] password for david: 
root@so1:/home/david# cd work/folder1/
root@so1:/home/david/work/folder1# ls
test_1.tex
root@so1:/home/david/work/folder1# vim test_1.tex
```

and when opening the file, it is possible to move the cursor where you point and click.

However, when opening the file as `user`:

```
root@so1:/home/david/work/folder1# exit
exit
david@so1:~$ cd work/folder1/
david@so1:~/work/folder1$ ls
test_1.tex
david@so1:~/work/folder1$ vi test_1.tex
```

the point-and-click cursor does not work (I actually prefer it this way, so I would prefer not to modify this).

If I now open the problematic file as `root`:

```
root@so1:/home/david/work/folder2/very-long-path-of-folders-and-subfolders--around_1000_characters_of_folders_and_subfolders# vi test_2.tex
```

I have the "jump-to-last-position" problem.

**6)** This is also even more interesting:

If I copy the file:

```
david@so1:~/work/folder2/very-long-path-of-folders-and-subfolders--around_1000_characters_of_folders_and_subfolders$ cp test_2.tex  ~/Documents/
```

and then open it:

```
david@so1:~/Documents$ vi test_2.tex
```

Then **the "jump-to-last-position" does work....**

**Where might be the problem then?**

## Answering @muru questions / suggestions:

If I do:

```
david@so1:~/work/folder2/very-long-path-of-folders-and-subfolders--around_1000_characters_of_folders_and_subfolders$ vim test_2.tex
```

and I do `:scriptnames` I receive the following:

```
  1: /usr/share/vim/vimrc
  2: /usr/share/vim/vim80/debian.vim
  3: ~/.vimrc
  4: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/syntax.vim
  5: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/synload.vim
  6: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/syncolor.vim
  7: /usr/share/vim/vim80/filetype.vim
  8: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
  9: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/gzip.vim
 10: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/logiPat.vim
 11: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/manpager.vim
 12: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/matchparen.vim
 13: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
 14: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/rrhelper.vim
 15: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/spellfile.vim
 16: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
 17: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/tohtml.vim
 18: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
 19: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
 20: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/tex.vim
```

The result of `:autocmd` is: http://paste.ubuntu.com/25060281/

(Since the output of that command is very long, I could not post it directly here)

## New update:

When running `ipython` on this problematic folder, I get this error message:

```
david@so1:~/work/folder2/very-long-path-of-folders-and-subfolders--around_1000_characters_of_folders_and_subfolders$ ipython    
[TerminalIPythonApp] ERROR | Current working directory doesn't exist.
```

as opposed to the expected result in any other folder:

```
david@so1:~/home/david/work/folder1$ ipython
Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit)| (default, Dec  6 2015, 18:08:32) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 4.1.2 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]:
```

So, something must be happening in this problematic folder

Comment: Can you add the output of `ls -l ~/.viminfo` to your question? Your problem somewhat resembles situations that have come down to that file's [ownership and permissions](https://askubuntu.com/a/382523/22949), so it would be good to rule out (or confirm) that possible cause. Are the files for which you are *not* having the problem files that you typically edit by running `vim` as root? Also, what is the output of `file /etc/alternatives/vim` (and is it what you expect)? Finally, do you know what packages the Software Updater installed, upgraded, or removed? (`/var/log/apt/history.log` may say.)

Comment: Add the output of `:scriptnames` and `:autocmd` after you start editing one of the problematic files, please.

Comment: @muru Thank you very much for your comment. See updated post with the result of your suggestions

Comment: Can you post to http://paste.ubuntu.com? That site you're using doesn't like adblockers and I don't like sites that don't like adblockers. Also `file` is an actual command, so `file /etc/alternatives/vim` is to be run as is. Alternatively, you can use `namei -lx /etc/alternatives/vim`.

Comment: @muru Thanks for your comment. I have posted to paste.ubuntu.com . I have also included the result for  `file /etc/alternatives/vim`

Comment: @EliahKagan  Thank you very much for your comment. See updated post with the result of your suggestions